Items disappear in ListView in a Popup when using LayoutMirroring
I have a problem where items disappear in my ListView which is in a popup when I use LayoutMirroring.
Sometimes the last item disappears and sometimes the second last item, depending on the LayoutMirroring.
The bug disappears when I comment out the lines which set the contentWidth and contentHeight.
at startup

after mirroring once, last item missing

after mirroring twice, second last item missing

I do not understand why this is happening, does anyone have an explanation?
The code example:
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQml 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
    id: root
    property bool mirrorLayout: false

    width: 800
    height: 600
    LayoutMirroring.enabled: mirrorLayout
    LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: mirrorLayout

    ColumnLayout {

        RowLayout {
            LayoutMirroring.enabled: false

            Button {
                text: "Open Popup"
                onClicked: popup.open()
            }

            Button {
                text: "Mirror Layout"
                onClicked: mirrorLayout = !mirrorLayout
            }

            Text {
                text: "IsMirrored:", mirrorLayout
            }
        }

        RowLayout {
            Repeater {
                model: 5
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    color: "red"
                    opacity: (5 - index) / 5
                    width: 40
                    height: 40

                    Text {
                        text: index + 1
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Popup {
        id: popup
        width: 400
        height: 400
        modal: true
        focus: true
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent

        contentItem: ListView {
            id: contentList
            implicitHeight: contentHeight
            implicitWidth: contentWidth
            contentHeight: contentItem.childrenRect.height
            contentWidth: contentItem.childrenRect.width
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            interactive: orientation === ListView.Vertical ? contentHeight > height : contentWidth > width
            clip: interactive

            LayoutMirroring.enabled: root.mirrorLayout
            LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: root.mirrorLayout

            model: 5
            delegate: Rectangle {
                color: "red"
                opacity: (5 - index) / 5
                width: 40
                height: 40

                Text {
                    text: index + 1
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


The bug disappears when I comment out the contentWidth line in the ListView, but I do not really understand why

Not sure if this is related to your problem or not, but I don't recommend using childrenRect to measure the size of a ListView. ListViews try to be smart about memory allocation so that if you have a 1000 items in the list it doesn't need to have 1000 instances of your delegate. So childrenRect will not necessarily be counting all of the items in your list, just the number of instances it decides to allocate. I would try setting contentWidth to something like (width of delegate) * (number of items).
